# Save song from document directory to iPhone Native library programatically in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a song in my doc directory (with all of its specifications), can we save it to iPod song library? I am specified abt song only.

Answer (score 0):

No. The iPod library access is read only. You cannot add media items to it.